# Is it Legal for an Object to Replace itself?

Tags: c++, memory, undefined-behavior

I have a feeling that this is not really legal or involves undefined behaviour, where the member object replaces itself with another instance. I searched here on StackOverflow and Google for quite a while and found mainly people who wanted to `delete this;`. I am not entirely sure if the `delete this;` questions are of the same situation, because I did not `new` my instance and I don't `delete` it.

Am I right?

Is there an easy way around this if I still need the code to do something like this?

```
struct Test;

struct Member {
    void fail();
    Test* test;
};

struct Test {
    Test(): member() {
        member.test = this;
    }

    void doStuff() {
        member.fail();
    }

    Member member;
};

void Member::fail() {
    test->member = Member(); // delete the object the current code is executing on
}

int main() {
    Test bla;
    bla.doStuff();
}
```

Comment: I do not see anything illegal in the code you posted.

Comment: @krzaq I am not entirely sure if it is the same situation, because I did not `new` my instance and I don't `delete` it.

Comment: @k​​​​​​​​​​​​​rzaq: _"in both cases it ends in the middle of the member function of that object"_ You mispelt "in neither case". Assigning to an object does utterly nothing to the object's lifetime.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit what a horrible typo!

Comment: @krzaq: The worst :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit hm, but does the lifetime really not end if you `delete this` in the middle of a member function?

Comment: @krzaq: That's a different question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> // delete the object the current code is executing on
> ```

Nah, it doesn't delete anything.

All you're doing is constructing a temporary `Member` object, then invoking `*this`'s copy assignment operator with that temporary as an argument.

From C++'s point of view, this is not a "replacement" of an object, nor does it "delete" the object. It's just a member function call. In this case, the only observable result is that `test` will be nulled after the call to `fail()`.

**Assigning to an object has no effect on its lifetime.**

Now, if you started playing around with `delete` and `new`, you'd have a problem.

Comment: So the lifetime of my original `member` ends after `fail()` returns?

Comment: @risingDarkness: That's the opposite of everything I just said.

Comment: Ah! Ok, I think i get it now. my original `member` does never even get destroyed, because the copy assignment operator just assigns the contents to the contents of the temporary. The temporary gets destroyed after the assignment, but that doesn't matter at all. Did I get it now?

Comment: @risingDarkness: Yeah. An assignment is just a copy (or move) of state from one object into another. You could even give `Member` an empty copy assignment operator and then literally nothing would happen at all.

Comment: thank you, that was actually quite obvious. I might need some Caffeine :)

Comment: @risingDarkness: Copy-assign some for me

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly legal as far as I know, although there's a simpler way to do it. If you've had problems with the above code, it's because the fail method resets the value of the "test" pointer to 0, and it becomes a null pointer. The below code performs the reset without those problems:

```
struct Member
{
    int value = 0;
    void step() 
    { 
        value++; 
        std::cout << "Member::step()" << std::endl; 
    }
    void fail() 
    { 
        *this = Member(); 
        std::cout << "Member::fail()" <<std::endl; 
    }
    void print() 
    { 
        std::cout << "X::print(): " << value << std::endl; 
    }
};
int main()
{
    Member x;
    x.print();
    x.step();
    x.print();
    x.fail();
    x.print(); 
}
```